# Problem with OP Player

Tags: problem-players, adnd-2e

One of the players in our group is really over powered. (I'm a fellow player, not the DM.) He's playing a wizard-rogue that's a few levels lower than everybody else since he missed a few sessions where EXP was given but he's still more powerful than us. He has maximum Intelligence and super regeneration and a number of other crazy abilities. On top of that his character has an expansive network of connections, so if he can't do something he can call in an NPC that can. The rest of the party is totally redundant, because he can do anything. How do I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. It might be useful to have some more information about the circumstances surrounding this PC's seemingly unreasonable power. Have you asked how the PC came by his super-regeneration? If he rolled his maximum Intelligence score in front of the group? (*My* dice *always* roll better when no one's watching!) If the network was developed during the campaign or if he just weaponized his background? What does the DM think about the PC? Has the DM offered other PC's the same opportunity for wacky abilities? And so on. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: It is something the whole group has an issue with?

Comment: its like the whole group but some of them won't say anything to the guy's face about it because they do it too.

Answer (score 5):

### Explain to the group that this is causing you unfun

Don't tell us what your issues are: tell the people you play with - we can't do anything about it: they can.

Explain *your* feelings in a non-confrontational way, remember, the other player's character is not the problem (necessarily), the way it makes *you* feel is.

Consider what a solution looks like to you and how that will make the *other* players feel. Do you want your character to be raised to a similar level to the other player's (and what that looks like practically) or do you want his character lowered to match your's (and what *that* looks like)?

Be very aware that calling for another player's character to be stripped of abilities is *likely* to upset them. Use tact.

See if you can reach an agreement that everyone is happy with (or at least can live with). If you can, great! If you can't: it may be time to find another group.